# In a homebrew formula, is there a way to specify a github version of a source repository (e.g., using a sha)?

Tags: github, homebrew

I am trying to put the finishing touches on a github formula.  I have been able to pull a zip file from github, but (for some unknown reason) it has the wrong version of files in it.  And I am trying to pull a specific version of the repository since (if I understand correctly) that is the customary way to build a formula.  So, pulling a tag is apparently frowned upon (which is also OK, because the few relevant tagged versions can be pulled with `HEAD` and `-devel`).

Is there a way to pull a specific version (aside from `HEAD` and tag) of a repository using the homebrew `GitDownloadStrategy`?

For reference, here's what I've got for the current formula:

```
class Geocouch < Formula
  homepage 'https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch'
  head 'https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch.git', :using => :git, :tag => '1.2.x'
  url 'https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch/zipball/couchdb1.2.zip'
  md5 '2e72424d67e369f2c649ed4ed01cdbc2'

  devel do
    head 'https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch.git', :using => :git, :tag => 'master'
    version '1.3.x'
  end
[...]
```

Since the `url` line grabs an undesirable version, I am trying to replace the `url` line with something like `:using => :git, :sha => 'eeeb0f2e8d0a77'`, but the `:sha` feature does not seem to work... though that's precisely what I need (I believe).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to use `:revision => 'eeeb0f2e8d0a77'` to achieve this.

Comment: Just what the doctore ordered.  Thank you!